# Boostrap Menu Alignment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have menu that has glypicons and one as dropdown. I am having an issue with alignment. It seems off.

A JsFiddle of the markup is below:

http://jsfiddle.net/tn1dtwe8/1/

You can see a screenshot below. The "Security" menu seems a big higher than its siblings.

[image]

Code:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li>
  <a href="/Setup/Database">
    <span style="margin:5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-hdd"></span>Setup Database
  </a>
</li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Security <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li>
  <a href="/Security">
    <span style="margin:5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Users
  </a>
</li>

                  <li class="active">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">
    <span style="margin:5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></span>Roles
  </a>
</li>

            </ul>
          </li>
<li>
  <a href="/Trades">
    <span style="margin:5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>Trades
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="/Licenses/Index">
    <span style="margin:5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode"></span>License
  </a>
</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible solutions is to add span with similar style in front of the "Sequrity" text

```
<span style="margin:5px;display:block;"></span>
```

Comment: Alternately, you could remove that inline styling altogether, and add a space after the span ("...glyphicon-icon"></span> Title).

Answer (score 0):

All other li items have icons which are pushing it down except security which dosen't have any icons with it. Adding icon with this will fix the issue;

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hdd" style="margin:5px"></span>Security <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w74de/5/)**